# Controller thread is waiting for the Async method response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and want to know little more about DeferredResult and @Async method. I created a method in controller as below and it worked fine.

```
   @GetMapping("/temp/{id}")
   public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> findByIdTemp(@PathVariable Long id) throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Request received : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        final DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
        ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> {
            System.out.println("Processing in separate thread");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(6000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            deferredResult.setResult(ResponseEntity.ok("ok"));
        });

        System.out.println("Thread freed : " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return deferredResult;
    }
```

Below is the output I received.

```
Request received : http-nio-8080-exec-1
Thread freed : http-nio-8080-exec-1
Processing in separate thread
```

Then I created @Async method in the service class and enablee async in the configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ThreadPoolConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private ExecutorConfiguration configuration;

    @Bean(name = "threadPool")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPool.setCorePoolSize(configuration.getDnCallBackPoolSize());
        return threadPool;
    }
}
```

```
    @Async("threadPool")
    public Future<String> getResult() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Separate thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        return new AsyncResult<>("Success");
    }
```

Then I called the service method from the controller class

```
    @GetMapping("/temp/{id}")
    public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> findByIdTemp(@PathVariable Long id) {

        System.out.println("Request received : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        final DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
        ResponseDTO responseDTO = null;
        try {
            responseDTO = ResponseDTO.builder()
                    .status(HttpStatus.OK.toString())
                    .body(productService.getResult().get()).build();

            ResponseEntity responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok(responseDTO);
            deferredResult.setResult(responseEntity);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Thread freed : " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return deferredResult;
    }
```

But the result I got was different

```
Request received : http-nio-8080-exec-1
Separate thread : dnCallBackPool-1
Thread freed : http-nio-8080-exec-1
```

It seems that the controller method is waiting for the response from the service method. Can anyone please tell me how to correctly use DeferredResult with @Async methods.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that the controller method is waiting for the response from the service method.

Yes the controller method is waiting for the response from the `productService`, Because `@Async` thread from `dnCallBackPool` is only responsible to execute `getResult()` method in `productService`.

But the code in `try-catch` block is executed by the web container threads (for example `http-nio-8080-exec-1`)

```
responseDTO = ResponseDTO.builder()
                .status(HttpStatus.OK.toString())
                .body(productService.getResult()**.get()**).build();
```

So `Future` object [get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--) call on `productService.getResult()`  is a blocking call, were current thread should wait until `@Async` thread complete it's process and return the result

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

So do the `get()` on `Future` object at the end of controller method, so that both the methods get executed parallely, below is an example

**Controller :**

```
 @GetMapping("/temp/{id}")
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> findByIdTemp(@PathVariable Long id) {

    System.out.println("Request received : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    final DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();

    Future<String> future = productService.getResult();   //Async call to service method
    System.out.println("Current Thread Execution: " +Thread.currentThread().getName());    // Execute parallely and print this line immediately 

    ResponseDTO responseDTO = null;
    try {
        responseDTO = ResponseDTO.builder()
                .status(HttpStatus.OK.toString())
                .body(future.get()).build();   // current thread waits for result

         System.out.println("Thread freed : " +Thread.currentThread().getName());    // This line prints as soon as service tasks completes
        ResponseEntity responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok(responseDTO);
        deferredResult.setResult(responseEntity);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return deferredResult;
```

**Service :**

```
  @Async("threadPool")
public Future<String> getResult() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Separate thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    Thread.sleep(6000);
    System.out.println("Separate thread Async task completed : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return new AsyncResult<>("Success");
}
```

Comment: Tanks for the reply. But still the controller method does not get free until the response from the service method. Below is the response I got.
`Request received : http-nio-8080-exec-1
Current Thread Execution: http-nio-8080-exec-1
Separate thread : dnCallBackPool-1
Separate thread Async task completed : dnCallBackPool-1
Thread freed : http-nio-8080-exec-1`
But the thread freed line should not wait for the response from service method.